# Get lowest number variable value

Tags: php, variables, numeric

I have 3 variables:

```
$last_article = 40;
$last_comment = 30;
$last_video = 20;
```

The variables are numeric and are days since the user's last posted article, comment and video.

I want a variable (`$last_activity`) that finds which of these 3 variables have lowest value and gets that value.

So in the list above, we can see that `$last_video` has lowest value. So `$last_activity` will be set to that value of `20`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`min`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php):

```
$last_activity = min($last_article, $last_comment, $last_video);
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know of min. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$last_activity = min($last_article, $last_comment, $last_video);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier if you would store all values in a array in the first place like that :

```
// using PHP 5.4
$last = [
    'article' => 40,
    'comment' => 30,
    'video' => 20,
    // other values
];
```

And then get the minimum value by using [min](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) :

`$minLast = min($last);`

Comment: I am already, just simplified it when I was asking the question ;)